# Neural Network for regression

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, regression

The way I understand regression for neural networks is weights being added to each `x-input` from the dataset. I want something slightly different.

I want weights added to the function that computes each `x-input` we'll call these `s-inputs`

The function to compute the `x-inputs` is a summation function of all `s-inputs` I want each `s-input` to have its own weight

So I say regression because I want the end result to be a beautiful continuous function between the mapping `x -> y`

...but that is accomplished through training the function that computes the `x-inputs`

It's baffling me because as we train the weights to compute say, `x1` we are also training the weights to compute `x2` since they are using the same summation function. So since the function to compute x-inputs is being trained simultaneously across all `x-inputs`, the plot `x -> y` will begin to morph. I need it to morph into something continuous.

You can think of it like this. The `y-value` is the ground truth, but we are adding weights to the function that computes the `x-value` -- the `s-inputs`

Can this be done? If so where should I start?

Comment: So you want the network to output y=f(wx), where w should be dependent of each data point x, while f() is shared across the data set, is that right?

Comment: @dontloo no I want f(f(wx))

Comment: @dontloo I think I found my answer here figure 10.6: https://www.byclb.com/TR/Tutorials/neural_networks/ch10_1.htm a three layered nn

Comment: all right, good luck