# Do more inputs improve neural networks?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm using a neural network for regression.

Please check this link: [Neural Network for regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746497/neural-network-for-regression)

As the number of inputs (`s-inputs` in my case) to the neural network increase, will the precision also increase?

Comment: probably, but not necessarily.

Comment: @cel please check the link above and share your thoughts

Comment: cel is right - there is no answer for such broad question. It **might** help, but may also harm the process. Machine learning is a complex domain, there is rarely answer to any question of form "will X improve results".

Answer (score 2):

As already said in comments a bigger training set does not always increase the network's precision. In order to answer your question more specifically you need to plot and analyze the learning curve of the network.

Learning curve depicts the dependency of the network's prediction error (for both training and validation sets) from the size of the training set.

First of all you need to have these two data sets. If you have only the training set, take about 30% of the records for the validation (shuffle the training set before the splitting).

Suppose the training set has `m` records. Do the following:

```
for i=1 to m
    train your network using only i training examples
    predict output of those training exaples, save the error
    predict output using THE WHOLE VALIDATION SET, save the error
end

plot the errors as a function of i
```

You will get something like this:

[image: Learning curve for a normal case]

The precision of your networks gets better if the validation error decreases. As you can see from the image, this is the case. Here increasing of the training set can definitely help.

There are two extreme cases when using this method:

- your network suffers on **high bias** (underfitting): your regularization parameter is too big, there are not enough polynomial features (in case of a neural network you might have too few units in the hidden layer)
- your network suffers on **high variance** (overfitting): there is no regularization at all or the regularization parameter is too small, there are too many polynomial features (your neural network might have too many layers with a lot of units)

The learning curve for the high bias case looks like this one (I droped the number of units in the hidden layer to 1):

[image: learning curve for high bias]

In this case you can not increase the network's precision by adding more training examples.

The learning curve for high variance case looks like this (I increased the number of units in the hidden layer up to 60 and set a very small regularization parameter):

[image: learning curve for high variance]

Here you have a greate oportunity to increase the precision of the network  adding new training examples!